# Ошибка function at 0x при работе с функцией

Tags: python, функции

Я начал изучать питон, и решил попробовать использовать функцию.
Я хотел, чтобы пользователь вводил номер месяца, потом использовал функцию, которая сверяла бы порядковый номер с названием и выдавала в print название этого месяца.
Но при вызове функции возникает ошибка function at 0x
Что я делаю не так?

```
template = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12}
while True:
number = int(input("Введите номер месяца = "))
if number in template:
    break
print ("для определения месяца по числу введите season в консоль")

def season(num):
num = number
if num == 1:
    print ("Январь")
elif num == 2:
    print ("Февраль")
elif num == 3:
    print ("Март")
elif num == 4:
    print ("Апрель")
elif num == 5:
    print ("Май")
elif num == 6:
    print ("Июнь")
elif num == 7:
    print ("Июль")
elif num == 8:
    print ("Август")
elif num == 9:
    print ("Сентябрь")
elif num == 10:
    print ("Октябрь")
elif num == 11:
    print ("Ноябрь")
elif num == 12:
    print ("Декабрь")
else:
    print("The End")
```

Скрин ошибки [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Когда вы вводите `season`, вы просто печатаете объект функции, это не ошибка. Если вы хотите **вызвать** функцию, нужно использовать скобочки и в скобочках записать передаваемые аргументы `season(number)`

Comment: И строчка `num = number` абсолютно бесполезная

Answer (score 0, accepted):

функции надо вызывать с параметрами в круглых скобках:

```
>>> import datetime

>>> def get_month(num):
...     return datetime.date(1900, num, 1).strftime('%B')

>>> get_month(int(input('Введите номер месяца: ')))
Введите номер месяца: 12
'December'
```